# How to obtain failed jobs from sql server agent through script?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to get the failed jobs which sql server agent failed to start or run through sql script...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I created a view to obtain the failed jobs in sql server

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.View_Failed_Jobs
    AS
    SELECT   Job.instance_id
        ,SysJobs.job_id
        ,SysJobs.name as 'JOB_NAME'
        ,SysJobSteps.step_name as 'STEP_NAME'
        ,Job.run_status
        ,Job.sql_message_id
        ,Job.sql_severity
        ,Job.message
        ,Job.exec_date
        ,Job.run_duration
        ,Job.server
        ,SysJobSteps.output_file_name
    FROM    (SELECT Instance.instance_id
        ,DBSysJobHistory.job_id
        ,DBSysJobHistory.step_id
        ,DBSysJobHistory.sql_message_id
        ,DBSysJobHistory.sql_severity
        ,DBSysJobHistory.message
        ,(CASE DBSysJobHistory.run_status
            WHEN 0 THEN 'Failed'
            WHEN 1 THEN 'Succeeded'
            WHEN 2 THEN 'Retry'
            WHEN 3 THEN 'Canceled'
            WHEN 4 THEN 'In progress'
        END) as run_status
        ,((SUBSTRING(CAST(DBSysJobHistory.run_date AS VARCHAR(8)), 5, 2) + '/'
        + SUBSTRING(CAST(DBSysJobHistory.run_date AS VARCHAR(8)), 7, 2) + '/'
        + SUBSTRING(CAST(DBSysJobHistory.run_date AS VARCHAR(8)), 1, 4) + ' '
        + SUBSTRING((REPLICATE('0',6-LEN(CAST(DBSysJobHistory.run_time AS varchar)))
        + CAST(DBSysJobHistory.run_time AS VARCHAR)), 1, 2) + ':'
        + SUBSTRING((REPLICATE('0',6-LEN(CAST(DBSysJobHistory.run_time AS VARCHAR)))
        + CAST(DBSysJobHistory.run_time AS VARCHAR)), 3, 2) + ':'
        + SUBSTRING((REPLICATE('0',6-LEN(CAST(DBSysJobHistory.run_time as varchar)))
        + CAST(DBSysJobHistory.run_time AS VARCHAR)), 5, 2))) AS 'exec_date'
        ,DBSysJobHistory.run_duration
        ,DBSysJobHistory.retries_attempted
        ,DBSysJobHistory.server
        FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory DBSysJobHistory
        JOIN (SELECT DBSysJobHistory.job_id
            ,DBSysJobHistory.step_id
            ,MAX(DBSysJobHistory.instance_id) as instance_id
            FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory DBSysJobHistory
            GROUP BY DBSysJobHistory.job_id
            ,DBSysJobHistory.step_id
            ) AS Instance ON DBSysJobHistory.instance_id = Instance.instance_id
        WHERE DBSysJobHistory.run_status <> 1
        ) AS Job
    JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs SysJobs
       ON (Job.job_id = SysJobs.job_id)
    JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps SysJobSteps
       ON (Job.job_id = SysJobSteps.job_id AND Job.step_id = SysJobSteps.step_id)
    GO
```

-- Now execute the select statement to query the failed jobs

```
Select * from View_Failed_Jobs
```

Comment: It should be noted that this script only lists jobs that failed the last time that it executed, and only lists the last failure.  If it subsequently succeeded then it is not shown at all by this script.  Which may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example for SQL Server 2008:
[SQL Server Agent Job Query Samples](http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/w/wiki/10351.sql-server-agent-job-query-samples)

You'll find a lot more if you google for "sql server failed jobs", but unfortunately most of the examples don't say if they work for SQL Server 2008, for example [this one](http://sqlschoolhouse.wordpress.com/2010/07/27/get-failed-jobs-from-sql-server-agent/).

---

**EDIT:**

Hint: when you copy the code from the first link, use the "view source" button:
[image: view source]

There's a "copy to clipboard" button as well which I tried first, but it generated some HTML tags in the SQL code which SQL Server complained about (and didn't let me execute the query).

Comment: Link rot. Here's the updated link for [SQL Server Agent Job Query Samples](http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/w/wiki/10351.sql-server-agent-job-query-samples.aspx).

Comment: Content rot, too. Some of the queries do not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

you can use  shortcut using sql agent-->job activity monitor.[image]