# In SQL Server, how will sysjobs tell which jobs have failed?

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server, how can we use `sysjobs` to find out which jobs have failed?

We have around 100 jobs running on SQL Server Agent. We have set up an email alert notification for any job failed.

Is there a way for us to run a query to identify a list of jobs that have failed.

Below query will provide, list of jobs enabled.

```
SELECT * 
FROM MSDB.dbo.sysjobs 
WHERE enabled = 1
```

Comment: I Googled "sql server agent query failed jobs" and the first two hits seems like a good place to start. [1] http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/88810/what-is-the-query-to-display-the-failed-sql-jobs [2] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577676/how-to-obtain-failed-jobs-from-sql-server-agent-through-script

Answer (score 0):

you will need to query sysjobhistory

```
FROM  msdb.dbo.sysjobs AS j
      INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory AS h ON j.job_id = h.job_id 
WHERE h.run_status = 0
```

also you can setup on Job Agent to email when a job failed.

Comment: I have Email Notification Alert for failed jobs. I am working on a ASP.Net page with Grid View on it. I need to populate list of Enabled jobs and any jobs failed on the top list.